Why does this program print 0?
#include<stdio.h>

int sum(int, int);

int main()
{
    printf("%f", sum(2, 4));
    return 0;
}

int sum(int a, int b){
    int c = a + b;
    return c;
}

Why does this program prints 0?
I used %f in printf, but still why does it print 0?
Why doesn't it convert int to float?

It prints 0 because you used %f.  The function returns an int; an int is passed to printf(); you told printf() it was passed a double, but it wasn't.  SO you get whatever result it happens to think is appropriate given that you told it fibs.  Don't lie to your compiler or the library.  Do pay attention to types — especially in printf().  Use %d instead of %f — and don't forget to end the output with a newline (so use "%d\n").

The behaviour of this program is undefined. It can do whatever. Why does it do this particular thing? Because it can.

It doesn't convert int to float because printf is a variadic function, and variadic functions do not convert between integer types and floating point types. For more details, see this question

You've just met undefined behavior. Your program might also have seemed to work perfectly. That would be worse than what you've seen. Turn on your compiler's warnings and/or turn them up, and pay attention to them.

"Why doesn't it convert int to float?"  Because it doesn't know that you passed it an int value.  There's no way for printf to know the types of the arguments following the format string; it just sees a sludge of bytes.  It only knows how to interpret those bytes based on the conversion specifiers you provide.  You told it to expect a double, it interprets the first sizeof (double) bytes as a double; it doesn't know that it has to convert from one format to the other.

Assuming it's even looking at the right set of bytes; some architectures pass the first few arguments via registers rather than the stack and use different sets of registers for int vs double, so it's possible printf isn't even looking at the right data.

Bits of float and int variables are stored differently in memory. Telling compiler to read int as float without a cast will produce garbage:
int main()
{
    int x = 6;
    float f = 6.0;
}

Here's the memory:
(gdb) x/4x &x
0x7fffffffdde8: 0x06    0x00    0x00    0x00
(gdb) x/4x &f
0x7fffffffddec: 0x00    0x00    0xc0    0x40

If you want to print out a float you should cast the return value of sum:
int main()
{
    printf("%f\n", (float) sum(2, 4));
    return 0;
}

